# Merge data with varying headers in Python or R

Tags: python, r, excel, dataframe, consolidation

I have an excel file with multiple sheets which need to be consolidated. However the column headers are varying from one another. Currently the data looks like this.

```
Sheet 1
+-------------+--------------+----------+--------+---------+---------+
| FISCAL_YEAR | COMPANY_CODE | ACCOUNTS | Header | Header1 | Header2 |
+-------------+--------------+----------+--------+---------+---------+
|          17 | Data         | Data     |      0 |       0 |       0 |
|          17 | Data         | Data     |      0 |       0 |       0 |
+-------------+--------------+----------+--------+---------+---------+

Sheet 2
+-------------+--------------+----------+---------+---------+
| FISCAL_YEAR | COMPANY_CODE | ACCOUNTS | Header3 | Header2 |
+-------------+--------------+----------+---------+---------+
|          15 | Data         | Data     |       0 |       0 |
|          15 | Data         | Data     |       0 |       0 |
+-------------+--------------+----------+---------+---------+

Sheet 3
+-------------+--------------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
| FISCAL_YEAR | COMPANY_CODE | ACCOUNTS | Header4 | Header1 | Header3 |
+-------------+--------------+----------+---------+---------+---------+
|          16 | Data         | Data     |       0 |       0 |       0 |
|          16 | Data         | Data     |       0 |       0 |       0 |
+-------------+--------------+----------+---------+---------+---------+

OUTPUT
+-------------+--------------+----------+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+
| FISCAL_YEAR | COMPANY_CODE | ACCOUNTS | Header | Header1 | Header2 | Header3 | Header4 | SheetName |
+-------------+--------------+----------+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+
|          17 | Data         | Data     | 0      | 0       | 0       | null    | null    | Sheet1    |
|          17 | Data         | Data     | 0      | 0       | 0       | null    | null    | Sheet1    |
|          15 | Data         | Data     | null   | null    | 0       | 0       | null    | Sheet2    |
|          15 | Data         | Data     | null   | null    | 0       | 0       | null    | Sheet2    |
|          16 | Data         | Data     | null   | 0       | null    | 0       | 0       | Sheet3    |
|          16 | Data         | Data     | null   | 0       | null    | 0       | 0       | Sheet3    |
+-------------+--------------+----------+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+
```

I am relatively new to Python. I have used Pandas and numpy.
I have as many as 60 sheets to work. Can anyone help me to understand how can I achieve this? If not python is there anyway other tool/method I should use? I could really use a code sample to start with.

Your help is really appreciated. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

filepath = r"filePath here"
sheets_dict = pd.read_excel(filepath, sheet_name=None)

full_table = pd.DataFrame()

#loop through sheets
for name, sheet in sheets_dict.items():
    sheet['sheet'] = name
    #sheet = sheet.rename(columns=lambda x: x.split('\n')[-1])
    full_table = full_table.append (sheet)

full_table.reset_index (inplace=True, drop=True)

#Write to Excel
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('consolidated_TB1.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
full_table.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using R, this is pretty easy to do.

```
library(openxlsx) # to read xlsx files
library(purrr)    # for the "map" function

wb <- loadWorkbook("path/filename.xlsx")
all_sheets <- names(wb)

merged_data <- map_df(all_sheets, ~ read.xlsx(wb, sheet = .x)
```

Comment: Thanks you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Using for loop and `rbind` in R :

```
for (i in file.list) {
    data <- rbind(data, read.xlsx(i, sheetIndex = 1))
}
```

`rbind` usage : To join two data frames (datasets) vertically, use the rbind function. The two data frames must have the same variables, but they do not have to be in the same order.

```
total <- rbind(data frameA, data frameB)
```

Comment: I think the whole point is that they do not all have the same variables.  If you aren't familiar, check out `bind_rows()` in `dplyr` - it will fill missing variables if only one data set has them.  Because `dplyr` and `purrr` are both designed to work together, the solution above will work even without all the variables being present in all files.